# Is this an appropriate question from this site?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

I'm looking for a site where I can ask a question regarding the math education system in the US versus Spain. I [asked for a site recommendation on the meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301483/is-there-a-site-where-i-can-ask-about-differences-between-the-educational-system), and they suggested this site might be appropriate, but I thought I should check on this site's specific meta first. My question is as follows:

> I live in the US, and as such, I'm used to my high school math courses
>   being essentially organized by subject material: algebra -> geometry
>   -> trigonometry -> precalculus -> calculus. I was talking to a Spanish friend about her math courses, and she said that in Spain, they don't
>   have those divisions. She was confused that our math courses would be
>   split up by subject material and said that her's are all together. So
>   my question is, how are mathematical topics of education divided
>   between different classes in Spain, and are those divisions at all
>   equivalent to the way we divide them in the US?

Is this an appropriate question for this site? Thanks.

Comment: Props for asking! I don't think it is a good fit here. Vaguely related topics have been discussed in [MathEducators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/2220/282). That one was at college level, and more about *content* as opposed to *structuring*. So I'm not sure about MESE either, but I think you have a better chance there.

Comment: Amazing question on amazing platform

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain? Would you rather I simply post my question without knowing if it's good?

Comment: @Phoenix votes on meta are a little different. On meta, on a question like this, it means "no, it is not a good question for this site" It probably isn't meant to say your post here in itself is bad.

Comment: Oh, alright, thanks for explaining that to me.